# How to set arguments for gnuplot used via fio - fio_generate_plot

Tags: label, arguments, gnuplot

The documentation I can find for fio_generate_plots states: "The script takes the title of the plot as only argument. It does not offer any additional options."

But I cannot figure out how to modify the title of the plot to insert arguments into gnuplot. For example: how would I modify the y axis label?

I don't really know my way around code, so I haven't been trying anything specific, just reading as much as I can and plugging things into the terminal. So far no luck.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you checked the actual script file? https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/master/tools/fio_generate_plots